# Spark UDF returns a length of field instead of length of value

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Consider the code below

```
object SparkUDFApp {    
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val df = ctx.read.json(".../example.json")
    df.registerTempTable("example")

    val fn = (_: String).length // % 10
    ctx.udf.register("len10", fn)

    val res0 = ctx sql "SELECT len10('id') FROM example LIMIT 1" map {_ getInt 0} collect

    println(res0.head)
  }
}
```

JSON example

```
{"id":529799371026485248,"text":"Example"}
```

The code should return a length of the field value from JSON (e.g. 'id' has value 18). But instead of returning '18' it returns '2', which is the length of 'id' I suppose.

So my question is how to rewrite UDF to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing the string `id` as a literal to your `UDF` so it is interpreted as one instead of a column (notice that it has 2 letters this is why it returns such number). To solve this just change the way how you formulate the `SQL` query.

E.g.

```
val res0 = ctx sql "SELECT len10(id) FROM example LIMIT 1" map {_ getInt 0} collect

// Or alternatively
val len10 = udf(word => word.length)
df.select(len10(df("id")).as("length")).show()
```